# find three distinct nonzero vectors a,b,c such that span(a,b)=span(b,c)=span(a,b,c) but span(a,c) is not equal to span(a,b,c)

Tags: vector-spaces

find three distinct nonzero vectors a,b,c in three dimension such that
 span(a,b)=span(b,c)=span(a,b,c)
but span(a,c) is not equal to span(a,b,c)

Comment: It’s not that tricky. Think about what this might imply for the dimensions of the various spans.

Comment: Consider $c$ a scalar multiple of $a$

Answer (score 1):

In 2 dimensions, take $a=(1,0)$, $b=(0,1)$, and $c=(2,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Trick:** We must have $c\parallel a$ in this case.

Comment: But $c \not = a$ by assumption